# running react bundle in Azure web app does not load json file

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

After building my react project it creates a bundle of files .js .json and index.html files.

I created a windows web app in azure.

When I deploy the bundle the page loads but none of the .json files do not load.  I have seen other examples they talk webconfig changes but since this is a react project that does not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  manually add a web.config in 'dist/prod' with the following to make it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

try it.
**Note** this for only static json files if your going to look dynamic content.you need add handler in config.files